# Can't compile xcode project using simulator after 7.1 update

Tags: ios, xcode

i have upgraded my xcode to support 7.1 sdk
since then i can't compile my projects using the simulator

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC  error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't open file:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/CarrierBundleUtilities.dylib
>   (No such file or directory)

Any ideas what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: iOS doesn't support dynamic libraries, does it?

Comment: What ? I can't understand what you trying to say

Comment: Ah, looks like I'm confusing myself; I thought you were building a dynamic library.  It looks like there is a missing `.dylib` in the SDK.  Do you know what `CarrierBundleUtilities.dylib` actually is and if you are explicitly linking with it?

Comment: Nope, dont know what is CarrierBundleUtilities , i can't find any reference to it and i'm not using it..

Comment: Can you provide more details. It could be because of some libraries you might be using dont support 7.1. thats just a guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the issue
One of my static libraries used CarrierBundleUtilities so i just removed it and it's working.

Still have no idea what is CarrierBundleUtilities and what is it for.